# Prevent Post Back on click of button - modalpopupextender

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a Modal window in my aspx page with a button inside it. On the click of the button , I have some javascript function that is called. However when I click the button, there is a PostBack occuring which I wish to disable. One of the ways I found to do that was by setting OkControlID /CancelControlID and assigning them to my Button ID. This prevents the postback but doesn't call my javascript function

Panel Code

```
<asp:Panel  ID="pnlAdd" runat="server"  Style="display: none" CssClass="ModalPanel">

//some code


<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit3" CssClass="Button"  
            runat="server" Text="Go Back" OnClientClick="return ValidatePopUpQuestions();"   width="65px" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Modal Pop up Code

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="pnlAdd_ModalPopupExtender" BehaviorID="pnlAdd" runat="server"
    DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="lblAdd" PopupControlID="pnlAdd" 
  DropShadow="false" BackgroundCssClass="Modal" >
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Label ID="lblAdd" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Is there anyway I can prevent the postBack from happening ?

Comment: If your `onClientClick` returns `false`, the page will not post back. Being that you're already returning a function there, you should be able to implement your logic in `ValidatePopUpQuestions()`, or even just always return `false` if you never want a postback.

Comment: can you just create a generic html button and bind your JS to that? Instead of using an asp object?  I believe if you have `runat="server"` it is going to execute the post back.

Comment: Try to format your question better. It's not clear.

Comment: @ZachM. I created a generic button but the postback happens nevertheless owing to the fault in my javascript coding. I don't want a postback ,so i am returning false always.

Comment: @Santi post it as answer, so OP can accept it